# How do I calculate relative contribution to a percentage change?

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question

Lets say there's a variable A, comprised of sub-variables B, C, and D.

From year 1 to year 2 the rate of A changed from 10% to 15%.

B makes up 20% of A, C makes up 50% of A, and D makes up the remaining 30% of A.

How do I thus calculate the relative contribution of each component to the total 50% change of A? (e.g 40% of the 50% change in A was due to component B, 30% due to component C, and 30% due to component D).

Comment: I don't think you have enough information right now to figure that out.

Comment: You need the contributions of $B,C,D$ to $A$ in each year.  Your will then be looking at percentages of percentages which typically lead to confused communications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear, but assuming the distribution of the portfolio is unchanged across time, then the growth rate of each component is exactly the same as the growth rate of the overall portfolio.

That is, if at any time $t$ the portfolio amount $A_t>0$ is made up of $n$ components, i.e.

$$A_t=A_{t,1}+...+A_{t,n}$$

and if at any time $t$ each component represents the same percentage of the portfolio, i.e.

$$A_{t,i}=p_i A_t,\\
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1, \quad p_i> 0$$

then the growth rate between times $T$ and $T'$ of any component is the same as that of the portfolio, i.e.

$$\frac{A_{T',i}-A_{T,i}}{A_{T,i}}=\frac{p_iA_{T'}-p_iA_T}{p_iA_T}=\frac{A_{T'}-A_T}{A_T}.$$